# Can't implement StaggeredGridView on Android

Tags: java, implementation

I just started working on android studio, and i've been told to use a StaggeredGridView in my app, i've already used some libraries like volley and such, but i can't seem to be able to implement the StaggeredGridView in my application, there's also very few information on how to do this in android studio. Can anyone tell my any steps i need to take to implement it in my application? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Go try [StaggeredGridView](https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridView) or [AndroidStaggeredGrid](https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid). They are great. I think you will love them.